# How do I split a PDF using Python, every page that contains a set of specific unique text

Tags: python, pdf

I have a large PDF file, and need to split it every 'X' pages, but where 'X' could vary.
I need it to split every page where a page contains the text 'Name:', but where the text after the 'Name: ' changes...

So page 1 might have 'Name: Sachin', then page 2 might also have 'Name: Sachin', but page 3 has 'Name: Sarah', so it should split from Pages 1 to 2, and then Page 3.

Here is a script I found, except it splits on every page, regardless.

https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/04/11/splitting-and-merging-pdfs-with-python/

Thanks in advance,

Sachin

**UPDATE**:

Here is some code that splits every page regardless, but which detects the name after the text 'Name:' is found and renames the split file accordingly, it has the name in the filename.

How though do I update the code so that if there are two consecutive pages with the same name found (after the text field 'Name:') that it DOES NOT SPLIT on that page, but merges the two pages with the same name into one pdf file?

Thanks again,

Sachin

```
import os
import re
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

pdf_file_path = 'Payslips.pdf'
file_base_name = pdf_file_path.replace('.pdf', '')
output_folder_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Output')

pdf = PdfFileReader(pdf_file_path)

for page_num in range(pdf.numPages):

    # Setup Objects & Classes
    pdfWriter = PdfFileWriter()
    pageObj = pdf.getPage(page_num)
    pdfWriter.addPage(pageObj)

    # Extract Text
    Text = pageObj.extractText() 

    # print(Text)
    MatchedTextArray = re.findall("Name:[^0-9]+?\s", Text)
    MatchedText = (MatchedTextArray[0].replace('Name:', '')).replace('\n', '')
   
    # Splitting on UpperCase
    res_pos = [i for i, e in enumerate(MatchedText+'A') if e.isupper()]
    res_list = [MatchedText[res_pos[j]:res_pos[j + 1]]
            for j in range(len(res_pos)-1)]

    # Extracting Firstname
    firstname = res_list[1]

    # Extracting Surname
    del res_list[0:2]
    surname = ''.join(res_list)


    with open(os.path.join(output_folder_path, 
        '{0}, {1} - {2}.pdf'.format(surname.upper(), firstname.upper(), file_base_name.upper())), 
        'wb') as f:
        pdfWriter.write(f)
        f.close()

    print("Split Page " + str(page_num))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
def pdf_splitter(path):
    fname = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]
    pdf = PdfFileReader(path)
    for page in range(pdf.getNumPages()):
        pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
        pdf_writer.addPage(pdf.getPage(page))
        output_filename = '{}_page_{}.pdf'.format(
            fname, page+1)
        if not your_condition: # only write of condition isn't met (anymore)
            with open("Give_it_a_name.txt", 'wb') as out:
                pdf_writer.write(out)
            print('Created: {}'.format("Give_it_a_name.txt"))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = 'w9.pdf'
    pdf_splitter(path)
```

Comment: Thank you. I see some of the logic. But how would I be able to read the text after the field 'Name: ' to be able to know whether the name on the page has changed? Would I not need an Python OCR library (I've heard of one called Tesseract) for that, and then store that in some kind of variable to know whether the name has changed or not? Then be able to give the new pdf file, the Name that was extracted by the OCR?

Comment: This depends on whether the pdf is a picture or in text format. if it's in text format you can read it with PyPDF2 else you will indeed need to use OCR.

Comment: Thanks! It is in text format. Can you recommend a Python OCR? Do you know how you would code for this in the above script?

Comment: Well if it's in text format you probably don't need OCR: to extract text look through the docs https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/. That being said pytesseract has worked for me in the past. > Do you know how you would code for this in the above script. You should firstly try this on your own, and if you really can't find anything you can make a new question on SO.

Comment: Thanks! I will try, I think instead of pytesseract, what I need to do is 'pdf mining', as the pdf is already text searchable, possibly using PDFminer. I will see...

Comment: I may need some further help with my update question above

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I solved it:

```
import os
import re
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

pdf_file_path = 'Payslips.pdf'
file_base_name = pdf_file_path.replace('.pdf', '')
output_folder_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Output')
pdf = PdfFileReader(pdf_file_path)

# Split Files
count = 0
for page_num in range(pdf.numPages):

    # Skip Parent Loop if needed
    if count > 0:
        count -= count
        continue
         
    # Setup Objects & Classes
    pdfWriter = PdfFileWriter()
    pageObj = pdf.getPage(page_num)
    pdfWriter.addPage(pageObj)

    # Search on Current Page
    Text = pageObj.extractText() 
    MatchedTextArray = re.findall("Name:[^0-9]+?\s", Text)
    MatchedText = (MatchedTextArray[0].replace('Name:', '')).replace('\n', '')

    # Search on following Pages
    i = page_num + 1
    while i < pdf.numPages:
        pageObjNext = pdf.getPage(i)
        TextNext = pageObjNext.extractText() 
        MatchedTextArrayNext = re.findall("Name:[^0-9]+?\s", TextNext)
        MatchedTextNext = (MatchedTextArrayNext[0].replace('Name:', '')).replace('\n', '')

        if MatchedText == MatchedTextNext:
            i += 1
            count += 1
            pdfWriter.addPage(pageObjNext)
        else:
            break

    # Splitting on UpperCase
    res_pos = [i for i, e in enumerate(MatchedText+'A') if e.isupper()]
    res_list = [MatchedText[res_pos[j]:res_pos[j + 1]] for j in range(len(res_pos)-1)]

    # Extracting Firstname
    firstname = res_list[1]

    # Extracting Surname
    surname = ''
    del res_list[0:2]
    if len(res_list) == 1:
        surname = surname + res_list[0]
    else:
        surname = surname + res_list[0]
        for i in (n+1 for n in range(len(res_list)-1)):
            if res_list[i-1][-1] == "-" or res_list[i-1][-1] == "'" :
                surname = surname + res_list[i]
            else:
                surname = surname + " " + res_list[i]
 
    # Write PDF File
    with open(os.path.join(output_folder_path, 
        '{0}, {1}'.format(surname.upper(), firstname.upper())), 'wb') as f:
        pdfWriter.write(f)
        f.close()

# Rename Files in Output Directory
files = os.listdir(output_folder_path)
for file in files:
    os.rename(os.path.join(output_folder_path, file), 
    os.path.join(output_folder_path, 'WE 25JAN 2022 - ' + file + ' - PAYSLIP' + '.pdf'))
```